# Query does not update database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When i execute this code to load a image and store in database it doesn't store.

```
$image=$_POST['image'];

$img = $_FILES['image']['name'];

if($img)
{
    $imgnew = date("YmdHis").".".end(explode('.',$img));
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$img_src.$imgnew);
    $sql = "UPDATE news SET `image` = '".$imgnew."' WHERE `id` = '".$id."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);                  
}
```

**My Form code is**

```
<input type="file" name="image" value="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" />
```

Comment: I modified the title because the code is not "loading an image" -- you're reporting trouble updating your database. Please include your form code so we can see that.

Comment: my form code is
<input type="file" name="image" value="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You call `exit()` before executing the query
2. There's an extra bracket (which is probably just a typo or another issue altogether)

Comment: it's just for echo purpose but still code not working.

Comment: i have update the code please check and answer thanks...

Comment: there is no output.... it store other field of form in the database but not image name.

Comment: yes it's working thanks....there is some fault in my browser cashe now it's solve thanks...

Answer (score 1):

It is important to check the results of functions that "do" something for you. You want to make sure it actually got done before you move forward assuming so. Both `move_uploaded_file` and `mysql_query` *might* fail.

If they do, they'll let you know with their return value (usually boolean FALSE). Capture that return and react appropriately. Then, if something goes wrong you don't have to scratch your head to figure out why!

```
$img_src = '/assuming/some/path/';
$img = false;
$error = false;
if (
    isset($_FILES['image']) && 
    $_FILES['image']['error'] != 4
) {
    $img = $_FILES['image'];
    switch ($img['error']) {
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
            $error = 'The uploaded file exceeds the maximum file size.';
            break;
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
            $error = 'Server error.  Please try again later.';
            break;
    }
    if (!$error) {
        $imgnew = date("YmdHis").".".end(explode('.',$img['name']));
        $result = move_uploaded_file($img['tmp_name'],$img_src.$imgnew);
        if (!$result)
            $error = 'File error while processing upload';
    }
    if (!$error) {
        $sql = "UPDATE news SET `image` = '".$imgnew."' WHERE `id` = '".$id."'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$result)
            $error = mysql_error();
    }
}

// do something useful with the error message, preferrably not this
if ($img && $error)
die('There was a problem updating the image: '.$error);
```

**Documentation**

PHP's `move_uploaded_file` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

PHP's `mysql_query` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php